# JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String \"2020-09-07T00:00:00.0+05:30 in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jackson-databind

**I am getting JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "2020-09-07T00:00:00.0+05:30 exception.**
**input :**

```
{
"sampleDate" : "2020-09-07T00:00:00.0+05:30"
}
```

SampleDto.java

```
public class SampleDto {
 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
private LocalDateTime sampleDate;
}
```

Comment: Where is LocalDateTimeSerializer from? Please be specific.

Comment: its from the package import import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.LocalDateTimeSerializer

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.Looks like the passed date format is not correct:

```
{
"sampleDate" : "2020-09-07T00:00:00.953Z"
}
```